# Are bitwise operations going to help me to serialize some bools?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles

I'm not used to binary files, and I'm trying to get the hang of it. I managed to store some integers and unsigned char, and read them without too much pain. Now, when I'm trying to save some booleans, I see that each of my bool takes exactly 1 octet in my file, which seems logical since a lone bool is stored in a char-sized data (correct me if I'm wrong!).

But since I'm going to have 3 or 4 bools to serialize, I figure it is a waste to store them like this : 00000001 00000001 00000000, for instance, when I could have 00000110. I guess to obtain this I should use bitwise operation, but I'm not very good with them... so could somebody tell me:

1. How to store up to 8 bools in a single octet using bitwise manipulations?
2. How to give proper values to (up to 8 bools) from a single octet using bitwise manipulation?
3. (And, bonus question, does anybody can recommend a simple, non-mathematical-oriented-mind like mine, bit manipulation tutorial if this exists? Everything I found I understood but could not put into practice...)

I'm using C++ but I guess most C-syntaxic languages will use the same kind of operation.

Comment: Which particular aspects of bitwise operations are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store bools in a byte:

```
bool flag; // value to store
unsigned char b = 0; // all false
int position; // ranges from 0..7
b = b | (flag << position);
```

To read it back:

```
flag = (b & (1 << position));
```

Comment: This shows how to do it, but maybe some explanation would also be helpful as the OP seemed unsure of the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to use std::bitset which allows you to use indexing to access individual bits (bools), then get the resulting value as an integer.  It also allows the reverse.

```
int main() {
  std::bitset<8> s;
  s[1] = s[2] = true;  // 0b_0000_0110
  cout << s.to_ulong() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I didn't known about std::bitset, thank you very much for making me discover it. However, I need an unsigned char and even thought I could convert to an int, then to the uchar, I'm going for the no-casting operations.

Comment: @Raveline: The cast from ulong to unsigned char is not a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Without wrapping in fancy template/pre-processor machinery:

- Set bit 3 in *var*:
  `var |= (1 << 3)`
- Set bit *n* in *var*:
  `var |= (1 << n)`
- Clear bit *n* in *var*:
  `var &= ~(1 << n)`
- Test bit *n* in *var*: (the `!!` ensures the result is 0 or 1)
  `!!(var & (1 << n))`

Comment: You should count from 0 not from 1.

Comment: @ralu: Eh? I think you'll find I do. "bit 3" above refers to the _fourth_ bit, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this in order.

1. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html
2. http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ConditionalSetOrClearBitsWithoutBranching

Some people willthink that 2nd link is way too hardcore, but once you will master simple manipulation, it will come handy.

Comment: Great link to _Bit Twiddling Hacks_. TVM

Answer (score 1):

Basic stuff first:

- The only combination of bits that means false is 00000000 all the others mean true i.e: 00001000,01010101
- 00000000 =  0(decimal), 00000001 = 2^0, 00000010 = 2^1, 00000100 = 2^2, …. ,10000000 = 2^7
- There is a big difference between the operands (&&, ||) and (&,|) the first ones give the result of the logic operation between the two numbers, for example:

  00000000 && 00000000 = false,

  01010101 && 10101010 = true

  00001100 || 00000000 = true,

  00000000 || 00000000 = false

  The second pair makes a bitwise operation (the logic operation between each bit of the numbers):

  00000000 & 00000000 = 00000000 = false

  00001111 & 11110000 = 00000000 = false

  01010101 & 10101001 = 00000001 = true

  00001111 | 11110000 = 11111111 = true

  00001100 | 00000011 =  00001111 = true

---

To work with this and play with the bits, you only need to know some basic tricks:

- To set a bit to 1 you make the operation | with an octet that has a 1 in that position and ceros in the rest.

**For example:** we want the first bit of the octet A to be 1 we make: A|00000001

- To set a bit to 0 you make the operation & with an octet that has a 0 in that position and ones in the rest.

**For example:** we want the last bit of the octet A to be 0 we make: A&01111111

- To get the Boolean value that holds a bit you make the operation & with an octet that has a 1 in that position and ceros in the rest.

**For example:** we want to see the value of the third bit of the octet A, we make: A&00000100, if A was XXXXX1XX we get 00000100 = true and if A was XXXXX0XX we get 00000000 = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can always serialize bitfields. Something like:

```
struct bools 
{
    bool a:1;
    bool b:1;
    bool c:1;
    bool d:1;
};
```

has a sizeof 1